# ¿Como puedo obtener en tiempo real el valor de un select?

Tags: php, javascript, variables, select, html-select

queria saber como obtener el valor de un select.
La situacion es que llamo a una tabla donde se muestran los valores de una base de datos y cree un boton de actualizar con un modal, el detalle es que quiero llamar el valor que me aparece en los select del modal pero me devuelve un valor vacio.

```
<div class="form">
          <h1>Pregunta 5</h1>
          <div class="row">            

              <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                            <label>¿Cuentas con un ahorro? </label>
                <div class="value">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="rs-select2 js-select-simple select--no-search">
                            <select class="form-control cp5" id="cuentaah" name="cuentaah">
                                <option value ="">Seleccione</option>
                                <option>SI</option>
                                <option>NO</option>
                            </select>
                            <div class="select-dropdown"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

          </div>
  </div>
```

Aqui muestro el script para obtener los datos de la tabla y mandarlos al modal

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on('click','a[data-role=actualizar]',function(){
                
                var cuentaah = $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=cuentaah]').text();

                $('#cuentaah').val(cuentaah);
                $('#myModal').modal('toggle');

            });
        });
</script>
```

Y aqui el script donde trato de obtener la opcion seleccionada del modal pero que me devuelve un valor vacio.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   var cuentaah = $('#cuentaah').val();

   $(".save").click(function(evento){

    console.log('Valor de Pregunta 5',cuentaah);

   });
});
</script>
```

¿Que puedo hacer?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

debes obtener el valor dentro de la funcion onclick, ya que al estar afuera se setear cuando se carga el documento y nunca mas se rescata el valor del combo.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   
   $(".save").click(function(evento){
    var cuentaah = $('#cuentaah').val();

    console.log('Valor de Pregunta 5',cuentaah);

   });
});
</script>
```